MO answer formalized in Lean
I have formalized an answer at
Homeomorphisms and "mod finite"
by @VilleSalo, in
a moderately-sized Lean file.
Outcome: his claims turned out to be 100% accurate.
(The only stumbling block was that for me, it was easier to prove continuity of the inverse directly rather than appealing to general theory of compact and Hausdorff spaces.)
Has anyone verified other MathOverflow answers?

Nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Great! I would welcome the trend, if more people do this kind of thing.

thank you for doing this!

The #1 most popular question on MO is "Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics".

The #8 most popular answer is "if a set is open, then it is not closed".

The #4 most popular answer is "1 + the product of the first n prime numbers is always prime".

The #2 most popular answer is "the trace of a product of any number of matrices is independent of their order"


Here are verifications that these are indeed false beliefs. :)
Alternative link since that one may be down

(I wasn't able to do the #1 most popular answer because I don't know how to work with vector subspace dimension (submodule rank) in Lean.)
